Send file content (log) of a Kubernets Container (AKS) to Azure Log Space
We run on Azure a Kubernets cluster (AKS). We now have some Docker Container that write Logfiles that are important to us, so we like to have them in the Azure log space. The same space as the console logs are collected.
Unfortunately we can not change the Software to write to the console. Is there a ways to mount the logfile and send it to the Azure log space?
Best regards
T

You can use the Azure Log Analytics agent to collect logs from your Docker containers and send them to the Azure log space. The agent can be installed on a Linux or Windows machine, and it can collect logs from various sources, including Docker containers.

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

You can send the log file content of a k8s container to Azure Log Analytics workspace. Create your workspace, in my case it's myLogAnalyticsWorkspace. Enable monitoring for the cluster
az aks enable-addons --resource-group arkorg --name test --addons monitoring --workspace-resource-id /subscriptions/abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop-qrst/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/myLogAnalyticsWorkspace


Create a ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace to specify the logs you want to collect from your container's log files.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: container-azm-ms-agentconfig
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  schema-version: v1
  config-version: ver1
  logs: |
    [
      {
        "file": "/var/log/nginx/access.log",
        "log-group": "nginx_access_logs",
        "interval": 60
      },
      {
        "file": "/var/log/nginx/error.log",
        "log-group": "nginx_error_logs",
        "interval": 60
      }
    ]


and apply
kubectl apply -f custom-log-configmap.yaml


Modify your deployment yaml accordingly to ensure the log file directory in your container is accessible to the monitoring agent.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: log-volume
          mountPath: /var/log/nginx
      volumes:
      - name: log-volume
        emptyDir: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-service
                port:
                  number: 80



verify the same
kubectl exec -it nginx-deployment-69bf4f8b9-vds6d -- sh


reference-

Collect container logs with Azure Monitor for containers


thanks for your answer. I need some time to test it. I will comeback and give feedback!

I found another solution for my problem. But this given answer looks correct. Thanks a lot!

How is this supposed to work? First of all, where did you get from the container-azm-ms-agentconfig schema as official docs doesn't mention it support logs array as you shown in your example. Secondly, how Container Insights agent is supposed to collect these access.log and error.log files? You configured it to collect /var/log/nginx/access.log but that is a path within a container. I doubt Container Insights agent can collect that from container... Can you explain please?
